# Как сделать разный размер у колонок GridView?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется GridView в который из базы подгружаются данные, как сделать что бы столбцы были разного размера в зависимости от контента в них (первый столбец большой, т.к. там ФИО, а два других в зависимости от оставшегося места)
Пробовал android:columnWidth="wrap_content", но wrap_content подсвечивается как ошибка

Comment: как вы делаете выглядит, что проще всё сделать через `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут XML android:columnWidth Задает фиксированную ширину для каждого столбца.

Источник: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:columnWidth

Comment: Так есть возможность при помощи других атрибутов задать разную ширину?

Comment: Конечно, я ссылочку скинул там все атрибуты есть

Comment: но через GridView нельзя будет так сделать